# Как получить содержимое сайта через php?

Tags: php, curl

Как получить содержимое сайта через php?

```
 <?php
Header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
include 'simple_html_dom.php';


$ch = curl_init();  

$curl_log = fopen("curl_log.txt", 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://anistar.ru/new/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result=iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', curl_exec($ch));
exit('Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
echo $curl_log;
?>
```

Данный код не работает. пустой экран белый. file_get тоже самое. Как быть? есть вообще возможность?.

Новые Логи

```
* About to connect() to anistar.ru port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 185.11.145.7... * connected
> GET /new/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
Host: anistar.ru
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 10:41:58 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=20
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< 
* Connection #0 to host anistar.ru left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: `exit('Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch));` перед `curl_close($ch); ` поставьте.

Comment: Поставил. Теперь отображается Ошибка curl:

Comment: Раз выдает только `Ошибка curl:`, то ошибка не в curl. Уберите команду из кода.

Comment: @Visman, наверху я логи выложил

Comment: Вы лучше в браузере посмотрите в код своей пустой страницы ;) Она в действительности не пустая приходит, а с js кодом. Вероятно на сайте стоит проверка как раз против парсинга.

Comment: Ну я заметил это. Ну а обойти ни как нельзя это?

Comment: Ну так вы посмотрите, что шлет в запросе к серверу браузер и в curl делайте точно также.

Comment: @Visman, вот код. http://pastebin.com/t3WLReLA. Куда смотреть?. Там ссылается на http://anistar.ru/new/ и делает какие то 3 запроса

Comment: Я вам намекал на заголовки, который браузер отправляет при запросе. Смотрите в инструментах разработчика (сеть) в своем браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
...
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

Внезапно экран **не белый**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Не стоит гадать на кофейной гуще при работе с Curl в PHP и зря терять время.

Можно включить логгирование в файл и смотреть, что происходит:

```
$curl_log = fopen("curl_log.txt", 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
```

Либо использовать, на мой взгляд, визуально более наглядный способ при отладке на локальном сервере. Можно установить Fiddler, либо другой Web Debugging Proxy (например Charles) и включить прокси в опциях сurl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8888");
```

Тогда все запросы  будут, как на ладони.

Comment: Обновил.........