# Как полностью эмулировать браузер в php?

Tags: php

Задача такая. Есть сайт (http://anistar.ru/new/), который нормально открывается в браузере. Мне нужно скачать страницу из кода на php, чтобы дальше ее распрасить, но сайт защищается от этого средствами JavaScript.

Как полностью эмулировать браузер в php? Или может есть какая-нибудь библиотека?
Я искал в гугле и пробовал curl, но у меня не получилось:

```
<?php
Header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251");

$headers = array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Host: anistar.ru',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0');

$ch = curl_init();

$curl_log = fopen("curl_log.txt", 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://anistar.ru/new/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result=gzdecode(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Я еще раз повторяю автору и всем отвечающим "**CURL ТУТ НИ ПРИ  ЧЕМ!!!**". На данном сайте стоит защита от парсинга в виде js скрипта, который проводит расчеты в браузере пользователя, прежде чем дать доступ к сайту.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить содержимое сайта через php?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448426/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать cookie. Задайте опции `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` и `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, детальнее [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)

в 90% `curl` справляется, но если целевой сайт использует что-то вроде CloudFlare, где стоит 3-5сек задержка и дальше редирект на `JavaScript`'e, в таком случае, лично меня спасал [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Если Вам нужно подождать, пока на целевом сайте выполнится какой-то `JavaScript` и только потом получить страницу, `PhantomJS` справится с данной задачей. К примеру, можно использовать вот эту библиотеку [jonnyw/php-phantomjs](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs)

```
<?php
    /** @var \JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client $client */
    $client = Client::getInstance();

    //храним куки
    $client->addOption('--cookies-file=some_file.txt');
    //все опции можно указать в конфиге и подгрузить его (формат json)
    $client->addOption('--config=path/to/config');

    //создаем объекты запроса и ответа
    $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('http://somepage.ru', 'GET');
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    //добавляем заголовок
    $request->addHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36')
         ->setDelay(5);//ставим timeout в секундах, сколько нужно ожидать, прежде чем вернуть страницу

    //посылаем запрос
    $client->send($request, $response);

    //получаем собственно страницу. По умолчанию страница возвращается в UTF-8
    $content = $response->getContent();
?>
```

Эта либа использует [jakoch/phantomjs-installer](https://packagist.org/packages/jakoch/phantomjs-installer) сама поставит все требуемые бинарники, но у меня почему-то так не завелось, пришлось самому скачивать бинарники и затем в клиенте указать путь к папке с ними

`$client->setBinDir(ROOT_DIR.'/bin');`

Comment: @Visman, а в чем собственно проблема? первая часть ответа как раз под вопрос ТС. Вторая же часть, как обойти защиту, о которой речь в комментариях под постом ТС. Или Вы из тех, кто не дочитывает до конца?

Comment: @xTIGRx достаточно просто скачать бинарник. Главное, чтоб у Вас на сервере была возможность выполнять внешнюю программу. Я к примеру, использую библиотеку https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs, там для запуска `PhantomJS` используется http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php

Comment: @nnick перенесите ссылки на php-phantomjs в сам ответ, добавьте пример использования - и получите пачку плюсов

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за совет